# How to use `google.protobuf.Any` in Go with primitive types?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have a message like

```
message Response {
  google.protobuf.Any id = 1;
  string message = 3;
}
```

and I would like to encode either an `int32` or `string` in ID.

I can achieve this by making some wrapper type

```
message IntWrapper {
  int32 id = 1;
}
```

and using `ptypes.MarshalAny` from `github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes` to marshal my new types since they implement `proto.Message`.

```
ptypes.MarshalAny(&myproto.IntWrapper{Id: 1})
```

I'd like to do this without the wrappers. Are there implementations of `proto.Message` somewhere for plain `int32`'s or `string`'s or another way to do this?

(Footnote: I do not want to implement `proto.Message`, but have it provided or autogenerated)

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot represent your numerical IDs as strings in Go?

Comment: There is no reason - I ended up doing this before I read your comment! Great idea. Still may be a nice-to-have in the ptypes package or something.

Answer (score 4):

Although wrapping is necessary, Protobuf conveniently provides wrappers for primitive types in [`google.protobuf.wrappers.proto`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto).

Here is an example of how to use `google.protobuf.Any` with primitive types in Go using the packages generated from these protos:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/anypb"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/wrapperspb"
)

func main() {
    strWrapper := wrapperspb.String("foo")
    strAny, _ := anypb.New(strWrapper)
    fmt.Println(strAny)

    intWrapper := wrapperspb.Int32(123)
    intAny, _ := anypb.New(intWrapper)
    fmt.Println(intAny)
}
```